# How to eliminate all <TAG/> and all attribute="" by XSLT?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

In a `xsl:stylesheet` I have this "identity like" transform, to eliminate comments, empty (terminal) tags and empty attributes... But the *second* `xsl:when` not works

```
  <xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name()='p' and not(./*) and not(normalize-space(.))"></xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="not(name()='img') and not(name()='br') and not(./*) and not(text())"
    ></xsl:when> <!-- this line NOT WORKS -->
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(.))"></xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="comment()"></xsl:template>
```

Whow to express condition to empty tags in this context?

PS: the "empty rules" are [explained here](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200010/post60080.html), I try to use it, but not see why not working.

Comment: The only reference for this is a mailing list?! :D rtfm! Btw, please accept answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty element is an element with no child nodes.

Template match priority is your friend ... the following should be the kind of identity stylesheet that meets your description plus what I think you are doing with image and break elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

<!--toss these-->
<xsl:template match="comment() | 
                    *[not(node())] |
                    @*[not(normalize-space())]"/>

<!--preserve these-->
<xsl:template match="img|br" priority="1">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
</xsl:template>

<!--preserve everything else-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! And it is a better and cleaner solution! About my tests ... When I add another template with `<xsl:value-of select="php:function('xslib::chgCase', .)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>`, where the function `xslib::chgCase` use DOM, it  destroy some of the "tossing cases" also in your stylesheet... But is some "side effect" of [registered functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/XSL/registerPHPFunctions)... Now I isolated.