# A `node()` is a tag?

Tags: xpath

Perhaps [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18025375/287948) (and of many others) is only a misconception about what I see at XML code as tag: it is detected by XPath as by `node()`? Or text and attributes are also detected?

When `.`, `*`, `@*`, `text()` and `node()` can be used for "tag detection"?

PS: my guess is that only `*`  and `node()` can tags (and `.` is like a `*` about  "children of this tag")... But I think I am wrong.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp Found by google: "node types xml" ;)

Comment: As RowlandShaw says "tag is an element in xml parlance", so, the answer is "node() detect tags but other things also..." and an important related question is "HOW TO DETECT ONLY ELEMENTS"? By `*`? (not working for me)...

Comment: why don't you accept his answer? it's seems that it is a common practice of you to not accept answers (had a look to your profile).

Comment: DELETE QUESTION OR REFORMULATE IT?  what is better for the Stackoverflow's community?

Comment: Ok, thanks @hek2mgl and RowlandShaw! And sorry (all readers) for not having depth the topic.

Comment: don't worry. Finally you made it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close; what you call a tag is an element in xml parlance, and an element is a type of node, as are attributes, text, comments, etc.

In terms of XPath expressions, `node()` selects all nodes, irrespective of type, whilst `*` selects nodes of type element, and `@*` would give you the attributes.

Comment: There are a XPATH1 for "only element" detection (or that [returns nodetype](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp)) ? See [my context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18025375/287948).

Comment: A real problem: * is detecting character entities (as nbsp), that is not a tag, is a part of the text

Comment: &nbsp; is not a valid xml entity; * shouldn't be selecting text nodes.

Comment: Yes, but say "for example NBSP" is more illustrative than "code 160"..  And the REAL PROBLEM you not answerd.

Comment: So what is your problem?