# How to add attribute to a parent-node conditioned by a child element, with indentity-transform in XSLT1?

Tags: algorithm, xslt

Like in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18025375/287948) I have difficulty to express simple things with XSLT1...

In a `xsl:stylesheet` I have this "identity like" transform to add an attribute `align="center"` into a `TD` tag with other attributes more (that must stay there)... The trigger for add `align` is the existence of a tag `CENTER` into the tag `TD`. (later the tag `CENTER` will be removed).

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="name()='td'  and .//center">
               <xsl:attribute name="align">center</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

THIS CODE DOES BOT WORK (`xsl:if` is ignored).

---

Need `td//center`, not only `td/center` neither `td/p/center`. Must be generic, for any `td//center`. Example of input:

```
<td colspan="2">
   <p><center>POF</center></p>
</td>
```

Comment: Are the elements called `td` and `center` or `TD` and `CENTER`?  Remember that XML is case-sensitive.  Can you give an example of the actual source XML you're trying to transform?

Comment: Aside from the fact that you need `.//center` instead of `//center` that looks like it should work correctly.  I suspect it's probably a namespace issue - does your input XML have `xmlns="..."` on the root element?  If so then you need to bind that same namespace to a prefix in the XSLT (e.g. `xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`) and then use that prefix in the XPath expressions (`.//h:center`)

Comment: Thanks, edited to `.//center`, but unfortunately not works...

Comment: ...OPS, IT IS WORKING! The problem now: `<td align="x"><p><center>` is not changed, only `<td><p><center>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From question comments:

> The problem now: `<td align="x"><p><center>` is not changed, only `<td><p><center>`

That will be because you're adding an `align` attribute using

```
<xsl:attribute name="align">center</xsl:attribute>
```

but *also* copying the existing one with

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
```

and when you try and add two attributes with the same name to the same element, the one added second (in this case the one copied from the input element) will win.

I would definitely split the logic into separate templates:

```
<!-- copy everything as-is except for more specific templates below -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- add align="center" to any td with a <center> descendant -->
<xsl:template match="td[.//center]">
  <td align="center">
    <!-- ignore any existing align attribute on the input td -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'align'] | node()" />
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove any <center> that's inside a td, but keep processing its children -->
<xsl:template match="td//center">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

This would transform

```
<td colspan="2" align="left">
   <p><center>POF</center></p>
</td>
```

into

```
<td align="center" colspan="2">
   <p>POF</p>
</td>
```

Note that it's `td[.//center]` - a `td` element that has a `center` element descendant - which is different from `td[//center]` - a `td` element that occurs in a document that contains any `center` element anywhere in it (not necessarily inside the `td`).

Comment: +1 - What you can also do is to split the apply-templates. First do `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` then output your new attribute(s) (`xsl:attribute`) and then `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`. The attributes will get overwritten if they already exist. This is handy if you have more than a couple of attributes to overwrite because you don't have to keep adding `local-name() != 'foo'` tests to the `select`.

Comment: @DanielHaley that's useful to know.  I wasn't sure what the rule was for adding two attribute nodes with the same name (first wins, last wins, or non-deterministic).  But looking now at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes) I see "adding an attribute to an element replaces any existing attribute of that element with the same expanded-name"

Answer (score 2):

With the following input XML:

```
<td colspan="2">
  <p>
    <center>POF</center>
  </p>
</td>
```

this XSL stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match any td elements with center descendants. -->
  <xsl:template match="td[.//center]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Add a new align attribute, then copy the original attributes and child nodes. -->
      <xsl:attribute name="align">center</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs this XML:

```
<td align="center" colspan="2">
  <p>
    <center>POF</center>
  </p>
</td>
```

And if you want to remove the 'center' element, add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="center"/>
```

Comment: THANKS! ops, needs //center ... I changed to `match="td[.//center]"`, and edited the question with an input example... No, your XSLT not works for me.

Comment: `td[.//center]`  and `td[//center]`   are the same?

Comment: No, they are not, for the reasons Ian Roberts gives. I've corrected my example accordingly. This stylesheet works for me and outputs the XML shown. That said, Ian Roberts' solution is more rigorous than mine.